# Selecting the closest input to adjust value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 input boxes, with radio buttons above each input box that fill in the values of the boxes. 5 Radio buttons for each box. Each box/button set should act independantly. They are created with the same classes and I adjust the value in the input boxes based on the radio button with the onclick radio button listener like so

```
document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[0].value=this.value; 
document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[1].value=this.value; 
document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[2].value=this.value;
```

Which doesn't work because it adjusts all 3, but I need it to adjust only the closest input. I've tried the below

```
jQuery('input').closest('nyp').find('.nyp-input');
adj.value=this.value;
```

The full snippet in context

```
<div class="nyp" data-price="0" data-max-price="" >
<div class="price-wrapper">
        <div class="donation-options">
        <label for="nyp-suggested-1">
            <input type="radio" name="nyp-suggested" value="20" id="nyp-suggested-1" onclick="
                var adj = jQuery('input').closest('nyp').find('.nyp-input');
                adj.value=this.value;                   
            "> $20
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-2">
            <input type="radio" name="nyp-suggested" value="50" id="nyp-suggested-2" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[0].value=this.value; document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[1].value=this.value; document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[2].value=this.value;"> $50
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-3">
            <input type="radio" name="nyp-suggested" value="100" id="nyp-suggested-3" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[0].value=this.value; document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[1].value=this.value; document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[2].value=this.value;"> $100
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-4">
            <input type="radio" name="nyp-suggested" value="500" id="nyp-suggested-4" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[0].value=this.value; document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[1].value=this.value; document.getElementsByClassName('nyp-input')[2].value=this.value;"> $500
        </label>            
    </div>
</div>      

<label for="nyp">
        Other ( $ ) </label>

<input id="nyp" name="nyp" type="text" value="0.00" title="nyp" class="input-text amount nyp-input text">
```

How can I get the closest nyp-input to adjust the value.

Comment: Did you share complete code? because i can see only one input text box.

Comment: They're all repeated objects of the full snippet. As in, the full snippet is repeated 3 times, for the 3 different sections. Hypothetically, the correct code should work the same for one or three, though it should be aware of the other two's existence not to mess with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```js
$(function(){
 $('.nyp-radio').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('.price-wrapper').children('[type="text"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nyp" data-price="0" data-max-price="" >
<div class="price-wrapper">
        <div class="donation-options">
        <label for="nyp-suggested-1">
            <input type="radio" class='nyp-radio' name="nyp-suggested" value="20" id="nyp-suggested-1" > $20
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-2">
            <input type="radio" class='nyp-radio' name="nyp-suggested" value="50" id="nyp-suggested-2" > $50
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-3">
            <input type="radio" class='nyp-radio' name="nyp-suggested" value="100" id="nyp-suggested-3" > $100
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-4">
            <input type="radio" class='nyp-radio' name="nyp-suggested" value="500" id="nyp-suggested-4" > $500
        </label>            
    </div>
    <label for="nyp">
        Other ( $ ) </label>

<input id="nyp" name="nyp" type="text" value="0.00" title="nyp" class="input-text amount nyp-input text">
</div>


<div class="nyp" data-price="0" data-max-price="" >
<div class="price-wrapper">
        <div class="donation-options">
        <label for="nyp-suggested-11">
            <input type="radio" class='nyp-radio' name="nyp-suggested1" value="20" id="nyp-suggested-11" > $20
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-12">
            <input type="radio" class='nyp-radio' name="nyp-suggested1" value="50" id="nyp-suggested-12" > $50
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-13">
            <input type="radio" class='nyp-radio' name="nyp-suggested1" value="100" id="nyp-suggested-13" > $100
        </label>
        <label for="nyp-suggested-14">
            <input type="radio" class='nyp-radio' name="nyp-suggested1" value="500" id="nyp-suggested-14" > $500
        </label>            
    </div>
    <label for="nyp">
        Other ( $ ) </label>

<input id="nyp" name="nyp" type="text" value="0.00" title="nyp" class="input-text amount nyp-input text">
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried nyp-input (last line) inside div has class price-wrapper (second line)

Comment: I changed this sample for run it on snippet, try this

Comment: I can see it does work in the snippet. I don't know how to add sequential numbers onto the end of the names though. As yours are all different. Is that the reason why yours works and mine doesn't still?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you may have is that the 3 "input boxes" contain inputs with the same IDs (basically you have for example nyp-suggested-1 3 times). You should try and generate different IDs keeping the same name for each group, but distinct between groups -example:

group1:

```
        <label for="nya1">
            <input type="radio" name="nya" value="20" id="nya1" > $20
        </label>
        <label for="nya2">
            <input type="radio" name="nya" value="50" id="nya2" > $50
        </label>
        <label for="nya3">
            <input type="radio" name="nya" value="100" id="nya3" > $100
        </label>
        <label for="nya4">
            <input type="radio" name="nya" value="500" id="nya4" > $500
        </label>
```

group 2:

```
    <label for="nyb1">
            <input type="radio" name="nyb" value="20" id="nyb1" > $20
        </label>
        <label for="nyb2">
            <input type="radio" name="nyb" value="50" id="nyb2" > $50
        </label>
        <label for="nyb3">
            <input type="radio" name="nyb" value="100" id="nyb3" > $100
        </label>
        <label for="nyb4">
            <input type="radio" name="nyb" value="500" id="nyb4" > $500
        </label>
```

Then you can select based on group name in jquery and update using the same value.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, and unfortunately that's just not possible

Comment: well, the problem is that somewhere in behind the browser sees two elements with the same ID as the same element (updates propagate to all the elements with the same ID), I know sometime ago I found this info somewhere, I will check to see if I still have the article..

Comment: Yeah, I need to move away from using id's and find a relative command based on the proximity of the element